# Json parse in square bracket with same name

Tags: python, json, parsing, samesite, square-bracket

I am successfully parsing an api in square brackets with a single name

API output :

```
{u'energyDetails': 
        {u'timeUnit': u'DAY', 
        u'meters': 
                [{u'values': 
                            [{  u'date': u'2022-08-30 00:00:00', 
                                u'value': 64225.0}], 
                                u'type': u'FeedIn'}], 
        u'unit': u'Wh'}}
```

with this command :

```
FeedIn = parsed_power['energyDetails']['meters'][0]['values'][0]['value']
```

I must add [0] becouse i have square bracket.....

How can i parse API with multiple value ( same name )
API output

```
{"energyDetails":
            {"timeUnit":"DAY",
            "unit":"Wh",
            "meters":
            [{"type":"FeedIn","values":
                            [{"date":"2022-08-30 00:00:00",
                            "value":64225.0}]},
            {"type":"SelfConsumption","values":
                            [{"date":"2022-08-30 00:00:00",
                                "value":15478.0}]}]}}
```

Thankyou for help

Answer (score 0):

You can get a list of values with something like this:

```
Values = [v['values'][0]['value'] for v in parsed_power['energyDetails']['meters']]
```

Or maybe you want to get each value by index: simply use `[1]` instead of `[0]` and so on.

```
FeedIn = parsed_power['energyDetails']['meters'][0]['values'][0]['value']
SelfConsumption = parsed_power['energyDetails']['meters'][1]['values'][0]['value']
```

And if you can have multiple values for each metric, you may want a list like this:

```
feed_ins = [v[0]['value'] for v in parsed_power['energyDetails']['meters'][0]['values']]
self_consumptions = [v[0]['value'] for v in parsed_power['energyDetails']['meters'][1]['values']]
```

Comment: great this work, but now i have second strange problem. I have in this API 5 values; FeedIN,Purchased,PRODUCTION,CONSUMPTION. I change every t[0]['values'] in 1,2,3,4, all work, but, every time I call the api, the result comes in a different order, and I need the value for further processing....   thankyou anyway, any other option? I'll probably have to call my API command for each value, but I only have 300 insights per day

Comment: @RafelLampič I think you should no go that way then. You should be generating a dict, for example.